# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost:3306/learning

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am using spring with mysql. I got the following error message.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost:3306/learning

I added the following dependecy in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I put the following configuration in servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="localhost:3306/learning" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean name="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
enter code here
```

Would you please give me some tips? My company wants me to change from oracle db to mysql and I am learning some example test. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the jar in your classpath?

Comment: Where is your mysql jar?

Comment: my jar file is under Maven dependencies classpath.